# Silent unattended uninstall switches for vmtools?

Tags: uninstall, vmware-tools

Looking for the **NON-MSIEXEC** totally silent uninstall switches for vmtools.

I know the silent install is VMware-tools--x86_64.exe /s /v /qn
I just need the uninstall, I feel like it would be similar but it is nowhere to be found in all the land.

/? gets me a installation box, but does not include the removal information.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I should also include that I have tried /c which unregisters vmtools and "disappears" but does not seem to uninstall anything...

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, trying to do an uninstall and reinstall for an automated server 2016 deploy that doesn't configure the service correctly on the first install. This is what I came up with that seems to work for uninstalling. Running in powershell, but should be easily adaptable for your use case.

```
Start-Process "setup64.exe" -ArgumentList '/S /v "/qn REBOOT=R REMOVE=ALL"' -Wait
```

I adapted the script on this page to include this line for uninstall as the /c flag doesn't seem to work correctly anymore.
https://scriptech.io/automatically-reinstalling-vmware-tools-on-server2016-after-the-first-attempt-fails-to-install-the-vmtools-service/